# Ways to find coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in $\prod_{i=1} ^\infty (x^2 - \frac{i^2π^2}{4})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

How to find the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ ($n\in N$) in this infinite product ?

$$\prod_{i=1} ^\infty (x^2 - \frac{(2i-1)^2π^2}{4})$$

By equating it with the series expansion of $\cos x$ , I know that the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ is $\frac{(-1)^n}{2n!}$ .

But, can you please share more methods to solve for it other than this ?

Comment: Comparing terms... because you related this to one of the Weierstrass products?

Comment: @FShrike Hi Thanks. But I don't know what you are talking about. I learnt this method while surfing on this site in the form of a euler solution of basel problem.

Comment: @FShrike I have edited the phrase.

Comment: The product (as written) simply diverges, not even saying that it has nothing to do with the cosine function (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Infinite_product_expansion) for the correct formula).

Comment: @metamorphy Doesn't $\cos x = 0$ if $x = \frac{nπ}{2}$ ? I saw similar solution to basel problem. Thanks .

Comment: What about $n=2$?

Comment: @metamorphy Oops I am sorry. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial $f(z)$ with roots $z_1,\cdots,z_n$ (counted with multiplicity) can be factored for some leading coefficient $a$ as $f(z)=a(z-z_1)\cdots(z-z_n)$. An entire function $f(z)$ of a complex variable (i.e. it has no poles) with infinitely many distinct poles cannot admit such a factorization, because such an infinite product will obviously diverge. For example $\sin(2\pi z)$ has the integers as its roots, but if you plug any noninteger $z$ into the infinite product

$$\cdots(z+2)(z+1)z(z-1)(z-2)\cdots$$

the factors will obviously get larger and larger as you go to the left and right without bound. (Not only does the product diverge, the *individual factors* diverge!) The fix is to consider a *different* way to factor a polynomial $f$: if its roots are nonzero,

$$ f(z)=a(-z_1)\cdots(-z_n)\left(1-\frac{z}{z_1}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{z}{z_n}\right). $$

In other words, we rescale each factor so that the individual factors tend to $1$ as $|z_n|\to\infty$. In complex analysis we learn all holomorphic functions have such a form, the **Weierstrass factorization**, but it includes some more caveats in general. When $f$'s roots all nonzero, have multiplicity $1$, and grow in size rapidly enough, we simply have the factorization

$$ f(z)=a(z)\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1=\frac{z}{z_1}\right)$$

for some nonvanishing (always nonzero) function $a(z)$ (for example, $e^z$). This is what we have to do for e.g. sine and cosine. Euler anticipated this: for the Basel problem, IIRC, he identified $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ numerically, but why would $\zeta(2)$ be related to $\pi$? You can divide by $\pi^2$ and get $\zeta(2)/\pi^2$ as the $x^2$ coefficient of an infinite product (thinking in terms of what we today call generating functions) which specifies all the zeros of sine. Apparently his initial sketch of this was not rigorous and simply assumed (correctly) that $a(z)=1$.

For cosine, we similarly have

$$ \cos(z)=\prod_{k=-\infty}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{-\pi/2+\pi k}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{4z^2}{(2n-1)^2\pi^2}\right). $$

Note the product required "folding" in half, i.e. multiplying the terms for a positive and nonnegative $k$ together with the difference-of-squares / product-of-conjugates formula. We multiply out such a product using Vieta's formulas:

$$ (1-b_1z^2)(1-b_2z^2)(1-b_3z^2)\cdots=1-(b_1+b_2+b_3+\cdots)z^2+\Big(\sum_{i<j}b_ib_j\Big)z^4-\cdots $$

The coefficient of $z^{2k}$ is the elementary symmetric polynomial $(-1)^ke_k(b_1,b_2,b_3,\cdots)$ evaluated at an infinite number of values $b_k=\frac{4}{(2n-1)^2\pi^2}$. The [Newton identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_elementary_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums) in turn tell us how to express the elementary symmetric polynomials $e_k$ in terms of the power sum symmetric polynomials $p_k$,

$$ p_k=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \Big(\frac{4}{(2j-1)^2\pi^2}\Big)^k=\Big(\frac{2}{\pi}\Big)^{2k}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2j-1)^k}=\Big(\frac{2}{\pi}\Big)^{2k}\Big(1-\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\Big)\zeta(2k), $$

where of course $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^s$ is the Riemann zeta function.

If I did all my math right, this gives us

$$ \cos(z)=1-{\small\frac{3\zeta(2)}{\pi^2}}\,z^2+{\small\frac{9\zeta(2)^2-15\zeta(4)}{2\pi^4}}\,z^4-{\small\frac{9\zeta(2)^3-45\zeta(2)\zeta(4)+42\zeta(6)}{2\pi^6}}\,z^6+\cdots $$

Comment: The coefficient appears to be non-elementary (as per my level). Can you please show that how is it equal to $\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n!)}$. Thanks !

Comment: @An_Elephant You show $(-1)^n/(2n)!$ is the $z^{2n}$ coefficient of $\cos(z)$ using the theory of Taylor series.